# Calculating Bounding rectangle of an arc drawn using <ArcSegment> in XAML

Tags: xaml, math

I am trying to calculate the bounding rectangle of an arc using the attributes of ArcSegment element of XAML.

The ArcSegment element takes following attributes:
1) StartPoint: Start point of arc
2) Point: End point of arc
3) Size: X and Y radii of ellipse
4) RotationAngle: Rotation angle of ellipse defining the arc with respect to X-axis
5) IsLargeArc: Flag indicating which part of ellipse to be drawn (i.e, small arc or large arc)
5) SweepDirection: Specifies Clockwise or Anti-Clockwise.

It is mentioned that ellipse will be scaled if it is impossible to render arc using combination of radii specified in the Size attribute and the angle of rotation specified in the RotationAngle attribute.

Can any one tell how actually they are calculating the scale factor for above mentioned case.

Answer (score 0):

They are actually referencing the semi-major and semi-minor axes, not the radii.  The end points are fixed.  That means that the scale must be adjusted if both the following angles are fixed (*and they are*): the angle subtended by the arc and the angle subtended  by the major axis and the x-axis.  You can't specify all those parameters and still freely choose *a* and *b* in the following, which is simply the parametric form of the ellipse [rotated back into alignment with the Y and X axes]

*x*(θ), *y*(θ) = (*a* cos θ, *b* sin θ)

That means that the scaling factor is simply the value *c* such that

*x*(φ), *y*(φ) = (*ca* cos φ, *cb* sin φ) = (x1, y1) for the initial value of φ

and

(*ca* cos φ, *cb* sin φ) = (x2, y2) for the final value of φ.  Obviously the explanation given here is correct only up to rotation of the ellipse.  But the rotation of a point about another point is not likely to cause you too much trouble.